# component.get is giving null on parents component's controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura-attribute

I am trying to pass a string literal to parent component as attribute.

Child Component code:

```
 <div class="slds-form-element slds-hint-parent slds-has-divider--bottom">
   <h1>{!v.assessment.N2__c}</h1>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
      <c:PicklistSelect objectName="DEL_Assessment__c" fieldName="N2__c" value="{!v.assessment.N2__c}"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Defining attribute on Parent component PicklistSelect :

```
<aura:attribute name="value" type="String"/>
```

Rendering code on parent component :

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<h1>'Passed literal value '+{!v.value}</h1>

Till here it is working well and on the layout of both parent and child the {!v.value} is printing.
```

But when i try to retriew the same in parent component PicklistSelect's controllers doInit function it is giving null

```
var value=component.get('v.value');
alert(value);
```

This alert is giving null, am i missing something while passing or initializing the attribute?

But when i pass a hard-coded value as below - in this case on parent controller the popup is giving the defined value

```
      <c:PicklistSelect objectName="DEL_Assessment__c" fieldName="N2__c" value="Hello"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, using attribute name as **value** is not recommended.
The reason for not getting the expected value in the alert is that the method named **doInit** is fired much before the value is passed to the component.
For getting the value, you can use another handler as follows,
Suppose your attribute name is **myvalue**,

```
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.myvalue}" action="{!c.methodName}"/>
```

So when the attribute value is changed, it can be captured in the method.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is that the init event of a Lightning Component happens before the contents have been rendered.

When you hard-code the value, Lightning knows the parameter value at "compile" time, so it is visible in doInit().

When you leave the picklist value to be set dynamically by c:PicklistSelect, that value is not known until the child component has been rendered.

Which gives you two options:

- Do your initialisation in a custom renderer, which is run after the the child components are rendered
- Add change listeners to the attribute